# Unable to load angular component in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, angular7

Unable to load angular component by injecting angular release reference script.

Basically, I have a normal index.html which doesn't have reference to angular release bundled script(main.js, runtime.js, polyfill.js). I tried to inject the scripting into the html by calling a jquery function like $('#angular').html(inject all the angular selector and script) but it doesn't load my angular component it just a normal html selector. I tried to put into normal way which is adding the angular selector and the script bundled reference and refresh the html page it will load the component. I wonder why it doesn't work if i injected the selector and reference on runtime.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="angularLayout">
  </div>
  <script>

  setTimeout(
      function()
      {
       $("#angularLayout").html("<app-root></app-root><script 
           src="runtime.js"></script>
           <script src="polyfills.js"></script>
           <script src="main.js"></script>")
       }, 3000);

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Expected result:
What I'm expecting is when I load the page it will trigger the function to inject the angular selector and script from the angular release bundled script to the html element to load angular component and display UI.

Actual Result:
It doesn't load anything after I injected the angular selector with the angular script bundled. In inspection, the selector is there but doesn't it doesn't have any content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$("#angularLayout").html()` does not executes your scripts tags. You need to do [`.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)